# Pointers to pointers: partitioning a linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, double-pointer

I'm trying to become more facile with pointers. So, for fun, I took the following C++ function that partitions a linked list around a value

```
void partitionList(lnode<int> *& head, int val) {
    lnode<int> * front = nullptr;
    lnode<int> * back = nullptr;
    lnode<int> * curr = head;

    while (curr) {
        lnode<int> * next = curr->next;
        if (curr->data < val) {
            curr->next = front;
            front = curr;
        } else {
            curr->next = back;
            back = curr;
        }
        curr = next;
    }

    curr = front;
    while (curr->next) {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr->next = back;
    head = front;
}
```

and I tried to change it to take a C-style double pointer instead. I did a mindless find-replace, which didn't work. Looking into it, I found the source of my problem, but I still don't really understand what's going on...

```
void partitionList(lnode<int> ** head, int val) {
    lnode<int> * front = nullptr;
    lnode<int> * back = nullptr;
    lnode<int> ** curr = head;

    while (*curr) {
        lnode<int> * entry = *curr;

        std::cout << (*curr)->data << std::endl; // On second loop, prints 2
        std::cout << entry->data << std::endl; // On second loop, prints 2

        lnode<int> * next = entry->next; // This assignment does something

        std::cout << entry->data << std::endl; // On second loop, prints 2
        std::cout << (*curr)->data << std::endl; // On second loop, prints 3!

        if ((*curr)->data < val) {
            (*curr)->next = front;
            front = *curr;
        } else {
            (*curr)->next = back;
            back = *curr;
        }
        curr = &next;
    }

    *curr = front;
    while ((*curr)->next) {
        (*curr) = (*curr)->next;
    }
    (*curr)->next = back;
    head = &front;
}

int main() {
    lnode<int> * tail = new lnode<int>(8, nullptr);
    lnode<int> * seven = new lnode<int>(7, tail);
    lnode<int> * six = new lnode<int>(6, seven);
    lnode<int> * five = new lnode<int>(5, six);
    lnode<int> * four = new lnode<int>(4, five);
    lnode<int> * three = new lnode<int>(3, four);
    lnode<int> * two = new lnode<int>(2, three);
    lnode<int> * head = new lnode<int>(1, two);

    partitionList(&head, 6);
}
```

On the first loop, all four of the debug print lines near the top of the function's while loop print "1". However, on the second loop, they print "2", "2", "2", "3"?

Can anyone explain what's going on? What's the right way to use a double pointer instead of a reference to a pointer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void partitionList(lnode<int> *& head, int val) {
    ...
    head = front; // <= head is modified
}
```

but here is not

```
void partitionList(lnode<int> ** head, int val) {
    ...
    head = &front; // try it with *head = front
}
```

and if you want a quick replace for this

```
void partitionList(lnode<int> *& head, int val) {
   ...
   lnode<int> * curr = head;
```

just write this:

```
void partitionList(lnode<int> ** head, int val) {
    ...
    lnode<int> * curr = *head;
```

Why did you modify `*cur` to `**cur`?

Comment: That makes sense, but I still don't understand what's going on with the print output. Why does doing this

`lnode<int> * next = entry->next;`

change the value of `(*curr)->data` and not `entry->data`?

Comment: Because of this: curr = &next; here "curr" variable got the address of local variable "next" and next = entry->next; will modify curr. So replace curr = &next; with *curr = next;

Comment: Ah, now I think I see. I get it, I get it. Thanks!